# Обращение к объекту в jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет.
Есть jQurey:

```
$('.clickable > div > img').click(function () {
$(this).addClass('active').parents('.clickable').find('> div >        img.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

есть Html:

```
        <div class='clickable'><div class="img-page"><img class="fix" src="4c1e484f811e2b1f822000a1f9751_5.jpg">
    <span>
    <a href="javascript:" onClick="window.open('c1e484f811e2b1f822000a1f9751_5.jpg');">Скачать</a>
    </span></div><div class="img-page"><img class="fix" src="90c484c111e29ade22000a1f9bd0_5.jpg">
    <span>
    <a href="javascript:" onClick="window.open('290c484c111e29ade22000a1f9bd0_5.jpg');">Скачать</a>
    </span></div>
```

### Вопрос:

Как мне обратиться к `<img>` для изменения его класса на `.active`?
Новичок в jQuery...

Comment: Заросли jQuery... Как обычно.

Comment: оно же изменяет, если надо программно, чего бы не послать ему `click()` ?   img.click();

Comment: [так надо ?](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Tt3vU/)

Comment: @eicto спасибо вы мне опять помогли. Дайте ваш ответ не в комментариях а в ответах причем вставив js код в ответ, что бы я смог закрыть вопрос и поднять вам рейтинг))

Answer (score 1):

Думаю можно так:

1. Принимаем клик
2. Ищем родителя
3. Ищем img
4. Убираем класс у картинки
5. Вставляем необходимый класс

   ```
   $('.clickable > div > img').click(function () {
       $(this).parent('.img-page').find('img').addClass('active');
   });
   ```

Я считаю событие `click` не совсем подходящим, найдите на jquery-docs.ru событие toggle. Пример на примере не пробовал, на спех мысли написал, возможно поможет.

Comment: Вот так надо.  

    $('.clickable > div.img-page').click(function () {  
    console.log(this);  
    $(this).addClass('active').parents('.clickable').find('> div.img-page.active').not(this).removeClass('active');  
    );

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest(".clickable").find("img").removeClass("active").end().end().addClass("active");
```